Trustless, Two-Party Randomness - Preventing Bruteforcing
This is a follow up question to this previous question, where it's asked how can two parties generate a shared random number. The consensus appears to be that party one can publish a commitment of their initial value, assuming the hash is secure, and is equal or greater in length than their initial value.
How would one prevent an adversary from precomputing all possible hashes or a subset of possible hashes to in certain instances allow them to manipulate the final shared number?
For example would it be worth publishing a salt with the commitment? My intuition says this wouldn't work and should instead consider expanding the length of the random number.
Finally how would one make sure that the number is sufficiently random for example a user could generate a truly random number which in an extremely rare case ends up being 0 and thus trivial to bruteforce. I understand the probablity of this is by definition extremely slim in a large enough range should I even consider this as a possibility and as a follow up what range should I consider? Is $2^{64}$ sufficient or should I be looking at $2^{256}$ instead?

For commonly used cryptographic hash functions, it should be very very difficult to find any collisions. The only known intentional SHA-1 collision took a lot of time and resources to calculate and more modern hash functions are considered much stronger than SHA-1. There are no known examples of a SHA-2 collision for example (or SHA-3, BLAKE2, Whirlpool, etc. as far as I know) despite how old and widely used SHA-2 is by now, so the adversary trying to calculate collisions does not seem like a pressing concern.
If you are extra paranoid, however, then you can implement the preventative measures you suggest. If we trust the security of the hash function, then it should be equally difficult for a malicious user to find collisions regardless of the length of the random number, so this doesn't help much. Choosing a hash function with larger digest sizes might help, eg. SHA-512 instead of SHA-256, since there is a larger pool of possible output values and this might reduce the risk of a collision further. But including a salt chosen by the other user in the commitment definitely helps prevent the attack you describe. The salting ensures that the no party can reuse a previously calculated hash collision and only has the time between receiveing the salt from the other user and publishing their commitment to try and find collisions. This would make it even more infeasible to carry out this attack.

Cryptographic hash functions are, by design, hard to brute force.  Hard may be an understatement.  Just counting from 0 to 2^256 with reasonable hardware assumptions (such as operating at the temperature of deep space) can take more energy than exists in the Milky Way Galaxy, much less actually storing the database.  We would certainly notice such a brute force attempt.
